# table-like formatting for data inside view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to arrange the data in the following view, so that it looks formatted in a nice, table-like structure:

```
            <View>
                {Object.entries(params.char).map(([key,value], index) =>
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'flex-start'}}> 
                        <Text key={key}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 14, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{key}</Text> : <Text style={{ fontSize: 14}}>{value}</Text> {"\n"}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                )}
            </View>
```

I've tried playing around with flex, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to look good.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I'd like for it to look something like this:

```
id        2
Name      Jake
Rating    ***
Working   7 Years
Where     4 Miles
Hire      Hire
Avatar    3
Map       4
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 'look good' is a very vague requirement. Do you have an example of how you'd like it to look?

Comment: thanks, good idea.  I've included an example of the desired format.

Comment: Add flex:1 for each text component to get them equal width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get clean columns, you need to do two loops (one for each column) with a `flex: 1`

something along the lines of:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
        {Object.keys(myArray).map((key, index) => <Text key={key}>{key}</Text>)}
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
        {Object.keys(myArray).map((key, index) => <Text key={key}>{myArray[key]}</Text>)}
    </View>
</View>
```

Alternatively, you could do it the way that you wrote if you used a fixed column width for one of the columns.